# Как задать координаты для движения объекта ?

Tags: javascript

Я реализовал класс Circle со свойствами:

- X - начальное значение координаты х
- Y - начальное значение координаты y
- Radius - значения ширины и высоты
- Color - цвет заливки

Метод `draw ()` - рисует на экране элемент который описан заданными свойствами;
Метод `move ({x = 0, y = 0})` - двигает отрисованный объект по вектору (x, y) - каждый период времени (100мс) изменяет (добавляет \ отнимает) координаты на значение x и y в соответствии.

Метод метод _update (), который менять синхронизирует позицию круга с соответствующими значениями color, x, y объекта.

**У меня возникает ошибка: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'left' of undefined", когда  вызываю метод: `circle.move({x: 10, y: 3});`**

```js
class Circle {
    constructor(options) {
        this.x = options.x;
        this.y = options.y;
        this.radius = options.radius;
        this.color = options.color;
    }

    draw() {
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.position = 'absolute';
        div.style.left = `${this.x}px`;
        div.style.top = `${this.y}px`;
        div.style.width = `${this.radius}px`;
        div.style.height = `${this.radius}px`;
        div.style.border = "1px solid;";
        div.style.borderRadius = "50%";
        div.style.backgroundColor = `${this.color}`;
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }

    setColor(newColor) {
        return this.color = newColor;
    }

    move({x = 0, y = 0}) {
        let circle = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        setInterval(function moved() {
            circle.style.left = x + "px";
            circle.style.top = y + "px";
        }, 100)
    }

    _update() {
        this.x = x.move;
        this.y = y.move;
    }
}
let options = {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    radius: 100,
    color: 'red'
};
let circle = new Circle(options);
circle.setColor("green");
circle.draw();
circle.move({x: 10, y: 3});
```

Comment: let circle = document.getElementsByTagName('div') - возвращает массив всех дивов на странице. Вам нужно либо указать индекс дива либо получить его другим методом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    move({x = 0, y = 0}) {
        let circle = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]; // !!!
        setInterval(function moved() {
            circle.style.left = circle.offsetLeft + x + "px"; // !!!
            circle.style.top = circle.offsetTop + y + "px";   // !!!
        }, 100)
    }
```

---

*P.S. Вы, кажется, перепутали радиус с диаметром.*

Comment: решил по-умничать)... исходя из логики кода `document.body.appendChild(div);`  лучше использовать  `[length-1]`, чем  `[0]`. Не так ли?

Comment: Согласен. Я бы скорее склонялся к уникальному `id`, который генерится в конструкторе, хранится в поле объекта, чей метод `move`, и назначется `div` элементу во время создания.